# Nested fragments - fragment started from a fragment does not inflate the layout xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying nested fragment because my xml layout starts to be difficult to maintain.

From a fragment I start a fragment when I click on the skip button. I tried both a normal start and a child fragment. On both case I get into the fragment in the inflate method but my screen stays empty. Of course when I call the fragment as a first level the layout inflates correctly.

Call to the 2nd fragment within the 1st one:

```
   skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            SelectServiceFragment ssf = new SelectServiceFragment();
            ft.add(ssf,"SelectService");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

SelectServiceFragment:

```
public class SelectServiceFragment extends Fragment {
    Context context;


    public SelectServiceFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = null;
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_svce_fragment, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }
```

and my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Select service!!!!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Did I miss something in nested fragments?

Comment: did you used chindfragment manager?

Comment: I tried both ways. FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); ft.replace(R.id.selsvcefrag, ssf); I tried the non child approach because I wanted to eliminate the framelayout (R.id.selsvcefrag). Both ways result in the inflate to show an empty screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            SelectServiceFragment ssf= new SelectServiceFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, ssf, "SelectService");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

try this way

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you are missing the most important thing. that you can change fragment from the base class method. the class in which you first replace method. make that method as a public method and pass it parameters with fragment class name.  Let say you have method in base class where you first replace or initiate fragment

```
public void replaceFragment( Fragment fragment) {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_home, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    // if you have used drawer_layout
    // othere wise no need of below lines
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

then call this method in any fragment and pass the fragment class name like this `((BaseClassName) getActivity()).replaceFragment(new ReportLostItem());`  this way you will be able to replace the fragment from any fragment class. accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: I don't get your point: what do you call base class? It does not explain why the inflate of the xml is empty? If I understood you correctly I can place a public method replaceFragment in my main_activity? When I tried your code as is, I have a conflict between support.v4 required by FragmentManager and android.app.Fragment. I tried to switch everything to support.v4 but I get more problems.

Comment: can you please share your full code. i think you are new to fragments. please share your main class and one fragment class code

Comment: you are very close to solve your problem. base class means your MainActivity. and import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; in your fragment class. and remove import android.app.fragemnt. this way you will be able to replace any fragment

Answer (score -2):

My excuses guys for having you lose your time on this!
All is working as expected!
the only thing I was doing as I was jumping from RelativeLayout is setvisibility(invisible) on the RL where the framelayout is.
Sorry!